# C# threading passing integer argument passes bad number

Tags: c#, multithreading

Good day to everyone.
Today I made up a school project with one thing bothering me.

My problem is, that I am passing argument to Thread function and when I print it to console via Console.WriteLine, it shows bad numbers.

```
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) autari[i] = new Thread(() => autar(i));
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) motorkari[i] = new Thread(() => motorkar(i + 10));
```

When I start them in same cycles, their functions do this:

```
static void motorkar(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("motorkar {0}", id);
        ...
```

It is not the order problem, but when I pass for example 0. Visual studio in Debug writes to console number 2 and without Debug it writes 1.

What can be the problem? I know that I can solve this by setting string name, but I am confused with this.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you're experiencing. Until then, a guess from my end would be that the problem is that you're starting N threads that each show the same number. The reason for this is that you're capturing a shared variable, whenever the thread starts it uses the current value of the `i` variable, and if several threads start when the same `i` variable *value* is present, they will all use the same value.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for response. I understand the problem now. Next time I will try harder to specify it more clearly and minimal, I am really appreciating this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the compiler creating you a closure under the hood. If you change the code around to the below you should get your expected output

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    var local = i;
    autari[i] = new Thread(() => autar(local))
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var local = i + 10;
    motorkari[i] = new Thread(() => motorkar(local))
}
```

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much. It works great.